# Incremental backup of FILESTREAM data?

Tags: sql-server, backup, filestream

Running `SQL Server 2012`. Consider the database below.

The `[Document]` table contains thousands of large files and has become some 100 GB large. The database must be backed up on a regular basis.

Now, let's say I run a full backup my database. Then I add *one* document of 1 MB. When the next backup is scheduled a new 100+ GB backup file will be created. Obviously, this is not very cost efficient. As far as I understand, `SQL Server` does not support incremental backups out of the box, but I sense it should be possible to do this manually. Especially for `FILESTREAM` data where the data resides on the file system.

**Q: How do I perform incremental backup of FILESTREAM data?**

```
CREATE DATABASE [FSTest]
GO

USE [FSTest]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [FSTest] ADD FILEGROUP [Document_FileStream] CONTAINS FILESTREAM
GO

ALTER DATABASE [FSTest] ADD FILE
    (NAME = 'Document_FileStream', FILENAME = 'C:\FSTest')
    TO FILEGROUP [Document_FileStream]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM NOT NULL,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're taking a full backup every time you take a backup. In my environments, I typically take a full backup once a week and differential backups the other days. A differential backup backs up changes since the last full backup (not, as some people assume, since the last differential!). In order to do a differential backup, you need only add the `with differential` clause to your normal backup. So something like:

```
backup [myDB] to disk 'c:\temp\myDB.bak' with init --full backup
backup [myDB] to disk 'c:\temp\myDB_diff.bak' with init, differential --diff backup
```

I should note that in order to *restore* in this scenario, you need to restore the full backup with the `with norecovery` clause and then restore your differential. So something like:

```
restore [myDB] from disk 'c:\temp\myDB.bak' with norecovery --full backup
restore [myDB] from disk 'c:\temp\myDB_diff.bak' with recovery --diff backup
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between incremental and differential backup?

Comment: What most people think of as "incremental" is "what changed since the last incremental backup". In SQL Server, that function is served more by transaction log backups. Differential backups are "what changed since the last full backup". So, if you take a differential yesterday and one today, today's will include all of yesterdays changes as well as today's. HTH.